# PHP Data in JustGage Javascript Values

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, raphael, justgage

Ive been trying this for quite some time now,firstly i use PHP for my server side script and mysql for database.i recently came across justgage.com for Online gage charts.

so the code for it is something like this:

```
var g = new JustGage({
   id: "gauge", 
   value: getRandomInt(350, 980), 
   min: 350,
   max: 980,
   title: "Lone Ranger",
   label: "miles traveled"
 });
```

so i want to set the value of the gage dynamically from php with javascript autorefresh,this is not possible if i just use the PHP short tags in the value field. In short i want to use the jusgage.com charts and dynamically get values from php in realtime without html refresh is this possible?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use ajax

Comment: Exactly,but how do i GET the values from PHP into the VALUE Field? i mean without a refresh!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `g.refresh(newValue)`.  This does not seem to be on the website and they don't have an API, but I saw it in the code.

Comment: thanks!,i saw that too! but how do i get the newValue from PHP dynamically ??

Comment: @AshrithGovind you need to use ajax for that.  With jQuery, something like: `$.get('thing.php', function (newValue) { g.refresh(newValue); });`

Comment: I did try using it like this,with refreshtime :
Ok i currently used this :$.get('value.php', function (newValue) { g1.refresh(newValue); }, 2500); 
where im echoing a value of 50 in value.php but still when i view the source it just has it has newValue. im unable to understand,im really sorry but im kida new to this! so pls bare me :)

Comment: Ahh it finally worked :) THANKS! i just had to set a refresh time!

Answer (score 5):

```
  var g1, g2;

  window.onload = function(){

    var g1 = new JustGage({
      id: "cpugauge", 
      value: 0, 
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      title: "CPU",
      label: "Load"
    });

    var g2 = new JustGage({
      id: "memgauge", 
      value: 0, 
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      title: "Memory",
      label: "Used"
    });

    setInterval(function() {
        $.get('ajax/cpu.php', function (newValue) { g1.refresh(newValue); });
        $.get('ajax/mem.php', function (newValue) { g2.refresh(newValue); });          
    }, 2500);
  };
```